# How to check if i'm in run-time or design time?

Tags: wpf

I developed some userControl that contain some information check on the 'IsVisible' method ( override method ).

When i using this usercontrol on some window - i see some error because the 'IsVisible' method look for some variable that is set on run-time.

How can i check if I'm in design time and the system is not running ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this);` This would return true if you are in design-time.

Comment: There a mistake in this answer : you may want to call DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(d) which can be found in System.ComponentModel.
Note that d must be an UIElement. This DesignerProperty is an attached property.

Answer (score 4):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            Console.WriteLine("The main window is in design mode.");
    }
}
```

The other answer is technically correct but I am providing this one to clarify the namespace and the usage.

Comment: This is not invocable, it has to be `GetIsInDesignMode` though.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic Oops, thanks for pointing that out! Fixed.