# Error in WPF Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting this weird error in the designer.
Visual Studio 2013 WPF - other views/windows are working fine.
This is happening when I have design time data (if I remove the design time data it works fine).

> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>     at
>   System.Windows.Controls.GridViewHeaderRowPresenter.OnLayoutUpdated(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>     at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
>     at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
>     at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
>     at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
>     at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
>   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteUIElement.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__f()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass2a`1.b__29()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.Invoke(Boolean
>   waitingInExternalCall)
>     at<
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.InvokeCall(Call
>   call)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessQueue(CallQueue
>   queue)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessInboundAsyncQueue(Int32
>   identity)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessMessage(Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean elevatedQuery, Boolean&
>   handled)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.OnWindowMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>     at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>     at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
>     at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
>     at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
>     at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
>     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)   
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Image of error
[image: Error]

Comment: The view's code-behind doesn't work in design time. Maybe a class field is not initialized via the "default constructor" code path. Use design time check described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978264/how-to-check-if-im-in-run-time-or-design-time

Comment: Share your xaml, looks like your culprit lies in it.

Comment: @ChrisW wasn't the xaml was actually a converter that didn't check for nulls, was I added a null check it worked fine -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by some converters not checking for null:
I added in the check for value == null and all is fine again.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

    {
        if (value == null) { return "White"; }
        var valueAsString = (string)value;

        if ( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueAsString) )
        {
            return "White";
        }

        if (valueAsString.ToLower().Contains("Late".ToLower()))
        {
            return "Yellow";
        }
        return "White";         
    }
```

MSDN also has some pointers on design time errors here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.XamlDesigner.ExceptionUI);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0)&rd=true

Value Converters
Your custom IValueConverter implementations should check for null and for the expected type in the first parameter of the Convert method. The following XAML shows a binding to Application.Current that fails at design time if the value converter is not implemented correctly.

Comment: Will repair the application, will also solve this one?